# Como puedo hacer que un div se incruste sobre otro y que este se autoajuste

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tengo este codigo

```css
.ticket-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 150px;
    left: 18px;
}

.tickets {
    background-color: #191C3D;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 980px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 50px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.tickets h1{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    top: 12px; left: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #fff;
}

.tickets h1::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #4C4E68;
    height: 1px;
    width: 913%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -3px;
}

.tickets ul li{
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 50px 86px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    top: 19px; left: -30px;
}

.tickets2-container{
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    top: 230px;
    left: 28px;
}
.tickets2{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 960px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0 50px;
}
.en-espera{
   color: #E8A50F;
}
.tickets2 ul {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tickets2 ul li {
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: bold;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: -9px;
}

.tickets2 .id {
    position: relative;
    left: 44px; top: 5px;
    color: #7C8098; 
}

.categoria{
    position: relative;
    left: 70vh; top: -15px; 
    color: #7C8098;
}
.tickets2 .ticket-titulo{
    position: relative;
    left: 29vh; top: -4px; 
    color: #7C8098;
}

.status{
    position: relative;
    left: 106vh; top: -26px;
    padding-right: 0;
}


.tickets2 .id::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 4vh;
    background-color: #4C4E68;
    height: 0.4px;
    width: 105%;
    border-radius: 25px;
    bottom: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ticket-container">
  <div class="tickets">
       <h1>My Tickets</h1>
       <ul>
        <li>ID</li>
        <li>Titulo</li>
        <li>Categoria</li>
        <li>Estado</li>
       </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tickets2-container">
<div class="tickets2">
      {{#each tickets}}
       <ul>
        <li class="id">{{this.ID}}</li>
        <li class="ticket-titulo">{{this.TITULO}}</li>
        <li class="categoria">{{this.CATEGORIA}}</li>
        <li class="status">{{this.ESTADO}}</li>
       </ul>
       {{/each}}
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lo que quiero hacer en general es que el div azul se autoajustes al div blanco que seria el contenido ese seria un ejemplo de lo que quiero hacer, el contenido blanco hice que automaticamente obtenga los datos y los vaya acomonando y se vaya expandiendo solo pero el div contenedor (el azul) no lo reconcoe y sigue siendo del mismo height, quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de que se ajuste automaticamente a el contenido blanco asi como el contenido se ajusta automaticamente al numero de lista que le llegue

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, si la respuesta te fue útil no olvides aceptarla, de esa forma ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a preguntas similares y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Hay unos pequeños errores, las propiedades que estás aplicando a `.ticket` para redondear las esquinas y para dar color deberían aplicarse al contenedor que es `ticket-container`, ya que éste es el `div` que debería ajustarse a lo que contenga, el otro `div` no contiene tus datos, es un `div` "hermano" (Es decir, está al mismo nivel) que tus datos.

Luego, cuando usas `display: flex` si deseas mostrar los `div` en forma de columna, no de fila, debes utilizar `flex-direction: column;`

Los `padding` que tienes, creo que están un poco grandes para mi gusto así que no modifiqué mucho esa parte, sólo el de `.tickets` para que no tuviera `padding-bottom`.

Una última cosa, en `.tickets2-container` no necesitas `position: fixed` deja que se acomode automáticamente y si necesitas modificar su posición utiliza `relative`.

Ejemplo:

```css
.ticket-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 15px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 150px;
    left: 18px;
    background-color: #191C3D;
}

.tickets {
    
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 980px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 50px 0px 50px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.tickets h1{
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    top: 12px; left: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #fff;
}

.tickets h1::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #4C4E68;
    height: 1px;
    width: 913%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -3px;
}

.tickets ul li{
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font: bold;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 50px 86px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    top: 19px; left: -30px;
}

.tickets2-container{
    display: flex;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.tickets2{
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 960px;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 0 50px;
}
.en-espera{
   color: #E8A50F;
}
.tickets2 ul {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.tickets2 ul li {
    list-style: none;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: bold;
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: -9px;
}

.tickets2 .id {
    position: relative;
    left: 44px; top: 5px;
    color: #7C8098; 
}

.categoria{
    position: relative;
    left: 70vh; top: -15px; 
    color: #7C8098;
}
.tickets2 .ticket-titulo{
    position: relative;
    left: 29vh; top: -4px; 
    color: #7C8098;
}

.status{
    position: relative;
    left: 106vh; top: -26px;
    padding-right: 0;
}


.tickets2 .id::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 4vh;
    background-color: #4C4E68;
    height: 0.4px;
    width: 105%;
    border-radius: 25px;
    bottom: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ticket-container">
  <div class="tickets">
       <h1>My Tickets</h1>
       <ul>
          <li>ID</li>
          <li>Titulo</li>
          <li>Categoria</li>
          <li>Estado</li>
       </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tickets2-container">
    <div class="tickets2">
          {{#each tickets}}
           <ul>
            <li class="id">{{this.ID}}</li>
            <li class="ticket-titulo">{{this.TITULO}}</li>
            <li class="categoria">{{this.CATEGORIA}}</li>
            <li class="status">{{this.ESTADO}}</li>
           </ul>
           {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```